# Will this program terminate for every Integer?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, pseudocode

In a Part Test for GATE Preparation there was a question :

```
f(n):
     if n is even: f(n) = n/2
     else f(n) = f(f(n-1))
```

I answered "It will terminate for all integers", because even for some negative integers, it will terminate as **Stack Overflow Error**.

But my friend disagreed saying that since this is not implemented code and just pseudocode, it will be infinite recursion in case of some negative integers.

Which answer is correct and why?

Comment: It doesn't terminated for n=-1. Mostly theoretical limits are considered in such cases.

Comment: @prakharlondhe: sorry, we don't need to known to see the infinte recursion, my bad.

Comment: If stack overflow is to be considered as termination, then all programs will terminate and it defeats the purpose of this question...

Comment: @xuq01 `while (true);` won't terminate nor, on anything sensible, cause stack overflow.

Comment: @TripeHound nor will calling `f(x) {return f(x);}` cause a stack overflow on anything _sensible_. It so happens that many programming languages aren't sensible and don't properly implement tail recursion, but that's an implementation defect.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I probably shouldn't have used "_on anything sensible_" because it's a completely different level of "_sensible_"... spotting and implementing tail recursion is _nice_ (or even _sensible_), but not doing so is only slightly "_not sensible_". Anything that implemented `while(true);` in a way that uses _any_ stack would most definitely be _not sensible_. The point is, unless you deliberately went out of your way to be awkward, `while(true);` will neither terminate nor trigger stack overflow.

Comment: @TripeHound well, I was writing tongue-in-cheek. Actually I think there can be legitimate reasons for not supporting tail-recursion, but there can also be legitimate reasons for _not supporting loops at all_ (but only something like structural recursion), namely when you want to use your language as a proof assistant and want to be able to ensure termination without having to bother solving the halting problem. In that case, “`while(true)`” will terminate very quickly indeed, namely with a compiler error.

Comment: @TripeHound Try [implementing loops in the `dc` language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)#Loops) - recursive macros is the only way to do it!  Fortunately `dc` is "sensible" enough to be fairly good at tail recursion

Comment: @TripeHound Could be running on a stack machine :-D Well, any real program terminates eventually, because it can't run past the destruction of universe... I don't see how this is essentially different from arguing "this program terminates because a SO kills it". In fact, I come from FP, so by this argument all functional programs must terminate...

Comment: @xuq01 I don't think the "destruction of the universe" counts as a solution to the halting problem.

Comment: @xuq01 You come from FP without TCO?

Comment: @TripeHound Neither do I. That's why I don't think a SO is a solution to the halting problem either. After all the TM, the SECD machine, etc., all have infinite memory and can't possibly SO.

Comment: @DavidYoung I am not sure you got my point... But then Scala doesn't have TCO so you could take that I'm talking about Scala, I suppose :-D

Comment: @xuq01 Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean, but you can write infinite loops in FP languages that never get any sort of overflow error and just run indefinitely as long as the language has TCO. Unless you're talking about the whole "destruction of the universe thing," but then I'm not sure why you'd bring up FP as a special case since it would apply equally to all languages. Also, as far as Scala specifically goes, even though it doesn't have TCO, I believe it has while loops (since it is "non-pure") which allow nontermination.

Comment: @DavidYoung Well, then you are using the imperative subset of Scala. I mentioned FP to illustrate the point that it's nonsensical to say "a program terminates because it SOs".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The correct answer is that this function does not terminate for all integers (specifically, it does not terminate on -1). Your friend is correct in stating that this is pseudocode and pseudocode does not terminate on a stack overflow. Pseudocode is not formally defined, but the idea is that it does what is says on the tin. If the code doesn't say "terminate with a stack overflow error" then there is no stack overflow error.

Even if this was a real programming language, the correct answer would still be "does not terminate", unless the use of a stack is part of the definition of the language. Most languages do not specify the behavior of programs that might overflow the stack, because it's difficult to know precisely how much stack a program will use.

If running the code on an actual interpreter or compiler causes a stack overflow, in many languages, that's a discrepancy between the formal semantics of the language and the implementation. It is generally understood that implementations of a language will only do what can be done on a concrete computer with finite memory. If the program dies with a stack overflow, you're supposed to buy a bigger computer, recompile the system if necessary to support all that memory, and try again. If the program is non-terminating then you may have to keep doing this forever.

Even the fact that a program will or will not overflow the stack is not well-defined, since some optimizations such as [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) can allow an infinite chain of function calls in constant-bound stack space. Some language specifications even mandate that implementations perform tail call optimization when possible (this is common in functional programming languages). For this function, `f(-1)` expands to `f(f(-2))`; the outer call to `f` is a tail call so it doesn't push anything on the stack, thus only `f(-2)` goes onto the stack, and that returns `-1`, so the stack is back to the same state it was in at the beginning. Thus with tail call optimization `f(-1)` loops forever in constant memory.

Comment: An example where the code translated to a programming language results in no stack overflow is Haskell. It just loops indefinitely: `let f :: Int -> Int; f n = if even n then n \`div\` 2 else f (f (n - 1)) in f (-1)`

Answer (score 5):

If we look at this in terms of the C language, an implementation is free to replace code with code that produces the same result in all cases where the original doesn't invoke undefined behaviour. So it can replace

```
f(n):
   if n is even: f(n) = n/2
   else f(n) = f(f(n-1))
```

with

```
f(n):
   if n is even: f(n) = n/2
   else f(n) = f((n-1) / 2)
```

Now the implementation is allowed to apply tail recursion:

```
f(n):
   while n is not even do n = (n-1) / 2
   f(n) = n/2
```

And this loops forever if and only if n = -1.

Comment: I think, in C, that invoking `f(-1)` is undefined behavior (the implementation may assume that every thread either terminates or does something else in a short list of activities that this function does not do), so the compiler can actually do anything it wants in that case!